# Length of json encoded facebook user profile

Tags: mysql, json, facebook, user-profile

Following:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$fbprofile = json_encode($user_profile);
```

I want to store $fbprofile in a MySQL varchar field.
What should be the max length of the field?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to store it in a `VARCHAR` field? My MySQL knowledge is a bit rusty, but I thought that `VARCHAR` is good for string attributes, but text of (unpredictable) length should be in `TEXT`. Since the length of the json response can be very lengthly (depending on the permission settings associated with your app), it seems to me you should use `TEXT`.

Comment: Thanks. On second thought this does sound like a good solution, given the way I'm going to use that table.